# How to replace one type of tag by another (<a ...>..</a> => <p>..</p>)

Tags: python, regex, parsing

I'm trying to figure out how to replace all `<a href....>TEXT</a>` tags by `<p>TEXT</p>` tags.

I've started with finding a pattern of `<a href...>` and `</a>` so I can replace them accordingly. Unfortunately it seems that it doesn't match the closest strings.

```
>>> s = '<td class="tt"><a href="#">Alert types</a></td>&#13;<td class="info">Vibration</td>&#13;      </tr><tr><td class="tt"><a href="#">Sound</a>'

>>> re.sub('<a h.*>','<p>',s)
```

returns

```
'<td class="tt"><p>'
```

instead of:

```
 '<td class="tt"><p>Alert types</a></td>&#13;<td class="info">Vibration</td>&#13;      </tr><tr><td class="tt"><p>Sound</a>'
```

Do you know how to make it match the closest strings between `.*`?

Comment: your regex has `h.*` so anything, try `<a h[^>]*>`

Comment: Use an HTML parser and serializer like [lxml](http://lxml.de/lxmlhtml.html#examples).

Comment: Do you really want to [use regex to parse HTML?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/6499571)

Comment: @depperm My approach is that "I don't care" what is between <a and > but it has to be the closest match so <a href="..."> yes, but <a href="..."> ... > not

Comment: @CésarLandesa If there were many things I want to do, I would consider something else but this is the only thing I want so I hoped that this is a most simple and lightweighted solution...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the following approach:

```
s = '<td class="tt"><a href="#">Alert types</a></td>&#13;<td class="info">Vibration</td>&#13;      </tr><tr><td class="tt"><a href="#">Sound</a>'
replaced = re.sub(r'<a[^>]+?>([\w\W]+?)<\/a>', r'<p>\1</p>', s)

print(replaced)
```

The  output:

```
<td class="tt"><p>Alert types</p></td>&#13;<td class="info">Vibration</td>&#13;      </tr><tr><td class="tt"><p>Sound</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure whether it is a good idea or not to do it using regex. But if you prefer regex, then here it is:

```
re.sub('<a [^>]*>([^<]*)</a>','<p>\\1</p>',s)
```

Using `([^<]*)` it is capturing the text between the `a` tag and in replacement it is using the group as `\\1`

Answer (score 0):

This Should Work.

Search By:

```
(<.+?>)(.+)(<.+?>)
```

Input:

```
<a href="#">Sound</a>
```

Replace with:

```
<p>$2</p>
```

Output:

```
<p>Sound</p>
```

Python Code:

```
# coding=utf8
# the above tag defines encoding for this document and is for Python 2.x compatibility

import re

regex = r"(<.+?>)(.+)(<.+?>)"

test_str = "<a href=\"#\">Sound</a>"

subst = "<p>$2</p>"

# You can manually specify the number of replacements by changing the 4th argument
result = re.sub(regex, subst, test_str, 0, re.MULTILINE)

if result:
    print (result)

# Note: for Python 2.7 compatibility, use ur"" to prefix the regex and u"" to prefix the test string and substitution.
```

See: https://regex101.com/r/j4OsbX/1